# How to get values from an object in a hashmap in kotlin android using mvvm

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, hashmap

I have a hashmap in my data/model class because the object key is dynamic

**ApiResponse**

```
data class ApiResponse(
val amount: String,
var rates: HashMap<String, Rates> = HashMap())
```

**Rates**

```
data class Rates(
val currency_name: String,
val rate: String,
val rate_for_amount: Double)
```

**View**

```
 val map: Map<String, Rates> map = result.data.rates
```

The data gotten from this comes in this format

```
{AFN=Rates(currency_name=Afghani, rate=1.0000, rate_for_amount=5.0)}
```

Now I have 2 questions.

**1** I am using MVVM, is it right that my Model (**Rates**) is interacting directly with my View? If No, how do I refactor for clean architecture.

**2** How do I get the value for the key `rate_for_amount` based on the data/result obtained, which is an object

Comment: please don't add the android studio tag unless you're specifically asking about a feature of the IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Q1**

- No, you should use the View Model to access the model from your view. To know more about the correct approach, you should [read this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-a-simple-example-ed5ac416317e)

**For Q2**

- If you want to get the value of rate_for_amount from a dynamic key, then you can get the key using a loop and then getting the value from that key.

---

```
fun getValues() {
   map.keys.forEach {
      val rateForAmount = map[it]?.rate_for_amount
   }
 }
```

---

**Example of how to bind your map's value from the view model to the view**

1. You will have to add binding in your view.
2. Add view model variable in your view's data tag.
3. In your view model, add a `MutableLiveData` variable.

   `val text = MutableLiveData<String>()`
4. Now call this variable in the setText tag of the text view (where you want to display the value).

   `<TextView` 
   `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`
   `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
   `android:text="@{viewModel.text}"/>`
5. Update the value of the view model's text variable. ( I am updating value from the view model only)

`fun getValues() {`
       `map.keys.forEach {`
          `val rateForAmount = map[it]?.rate_for_amount`
          `text.value = rateForAmount.toString()`
          `viewModel.text.value = rateForAmount.toString()`
       `}`
     `}`

Comment: Working. Thanks

For number 1. How do I implement the map in my viewModel and use it in my view. Just an example plsss. I am using HILT for DI

Comment: @Ibramazin Check the answer's new edit. I think this will work for you!!